# .Net jQuery WYSIWYG Hiding on AJAX Postback

Tags: c#, jquery, .net, ajax

I'm using the WYSIWYG editor summernote in my .Net application. When I postback using AJAX the form works fine however the WYSIWYG disappears. I gather I need to run the initialiser again. I'm using the below code to attempt that.

```
<script>
$('#<%=txtDescription.ClientID%>').summernote({
    tabsize: 2,
    height: 100,
    toolbar: [
        ['style', ['bold', 'italic', 'underline']],
        ['color', ['color']],
        ['para', ['ol', 'paragraph']],
        ['insert', ['link', 'picture', 'video', 'table', 'hr']]
    ]
});

var prm = Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance();
prm.add_endRequest(function (s, e) {
    $('#<%=txtDescription.ClientID%>').summernote({
        tabsize: 2,
        height: 100,
        toolbar: [
            ['style', ['bold', 'italic', 'underline']],
            ['color', ['color']],
            ['para', ['ol', 'paragraph']],
            ['insert', ['link', 'picture', 'video', 'table', 'hr']]
        ]
    });
});
```

It's not reloading the editor and I'm getting the error:

> Uncaught TypeError: $(...).summernote is not a function
>       at Array.....

[Error text in Chrome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7TrGR.png)

Answer (score 0):

I think the main issue was my jQuery and Bootstrap references not being accurate. The below code worked in the end.

```
function pageLoad() { // this gets fired when the UpdatePanel.Update() completes
                            $('#<%=txtDescription.ClientID%>').summernote({
                                tabsize: 2,
                                height: 100,
                                toolbar: [
                                    ['style', ['bold', 'italic', 'underline']],
                                    ['color', ['color']],
                                    ['para', ['ol', 'paragraph']],
                                    ['insert', ['link', 'picture', 'video', 'table', 'hr']]
                                ]
                            });
                        }
```